# Onload event on svg element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to execute some function when svg is completely loaded. I tried this code:

```
    var svgContainer = d3.select("#" + network.container_id)
                         .append("svg")
                         .attr("id", "svg_network")
                         .attr("width", width)
                         .on("load", function (d, i) { console.log('svg');})
                         .attr("height", height);
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to somehow catch the event when svg is loaded or rendered? And is it possible to catch the same event on such elements as text or tspan?

Comment: They're usually just a form of markup so a script at document ready, or after the element, will be able to reference it

Comment: Chances are that this code is only being run after everything has been loaded. Try adding it statically and not through Javascript.